# Foldr applied to just one argument

Tags: haskell, fold

So I've got the function that will return `True` if the number n is the result of applying bitwise or to any subsequence of xs :

`checkBits xs n = not $ null $ filter (==n) $ map (foldr (.|.) zeroBits) (subsequences xs)`

Now the thing I don't get is that the `foldr` is given `(.|.)` and `zeroBits`, but didn't I need another argument for `foldr`.
Like I understand the function of `foldr`, you apply it to a function, which is in that case `(.|.)`, to a "starting value", which I guess is `zeroBits`, but what about the `t a`, which is mentioned in:

`Prelude>:t foldr
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`

Is there anything I'm missing? The code above by the way works like it should.

Comment: Haskell doesn't require you to supply all the arguments at once. If you only supply the first two, you are _partially applying_ the function, and the result is another function that wants the last two. This is a pervasive feature of Haskell, not limited to `foldr`.

Comment: Try asking GHCI about the type of `foldr (.|.) zeroBits` too: since it's apparently a valid expression it must have some type, right? What do you think that type means? How did it get that type?

Comment: Oh I didn't knew that. Sounds like a cool feature! Thanks I got it !

Comment: Try googling for "partial application" and "currying". In Haskell, we pretend that there are multiple-argument functions, but actually every function takes exactly one argument, only -- it can however return another function which takes another argument, creating the illusion that two arguments are passed to the original function.

Comment: @chi Will do it later on. Good explanation btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foldr` with a "missing" argument returns a function that takes a single argument (the one that was missing).

You can then proceed to `map` that function over your `subsequences xs` (meaning that each of these subsequences is passed to your specialized foldr function as the "missing" argument).

This is a very common and useful pattern that allows you to create specialized function by fixing a subset of parameters to a more general function.

---

In your example, the "specialized function" remains anonymous. If that becomes too hard to read (or the function is useful in many places), you could give it a name.

```
--  create a new function that takes the first ten list elements 
top10 = take 10       -- call take with a "missing parameter"

-- as opposed to
ten = take 10 myList  -- call take with all parameters to get a list
```

---

It may help (or confuse) to think of Haskell functions as only taking a single parameter and returning a function that takes the next parameter (which in turn returns a function that takes the third parameter or a plain result if that was the last one). An expression like `take 1 list` can then be read as `(take 1) list`:  Call `take 1` to obtain a function, then call that function on the `list` to get the final result.